# React TS Скормить картинку в video елемент и указать длительность

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs, typescript

Появилась задача...

1. Есть картинка Example.jpg
2. Есть video html5 елемент в React приложении
3. Есть длительность псевдовидео

Вопрос: Есть ли возможность создать видеофайл(из картинки) который скушает `video` и проиграет его нужное время?

Создать img елемент и повесить таймер не расматривается из за ограничений создаваемого сервиса.

Использовать npm пакеты тоже нельзя

Comment: *Есть ли возможность создать видеофайл(из картинки)* - **нет**